# Why is my HTML select not letting me access is options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select element in my html. I fill it with options from JS.

```
<select name="send_hour" class="input-mini" id="send_hour"></select>
```

I have javascript that tries to access its options length.

```
$("#send_hour").options.length
```

When I put a breakpoint at this line and then type the following into the console I get the below.

```
hr = $("#send_hour");
```

I GET THIS IN THE CONSOLE (if I click the down arrow next to hr):

```
hr = $("#send_hour");
{…}
0: <select id="send_hour" class="input-mini" name="send_hour">
context: HTMLDocument https://bubbb.com/requester/index#
length: 1
selector: "#send_hour"
__proto__: Object { jquery: "1.11.3", constructor: at(), length: 0, … }
```

IF I OPEN THE DOWN ARROW NEXT TO {…} I CAN SEE THE OPTIONS PROPERTY.

Why is `$("#send_hour").options` not working to get the options? It comes back undefined?

Comment: `options` isn't a jQuery property or method (it is legacy DOM notation though). Did you mean `$("#send_hour option").length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#send_hour").options` isn't valid jQuery. What you're looking for it `$("#send_hour option")`.

For HTML like,

```
<select id="send_hour">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
```

`#send_hour option` means find the element with the ID send_hour, and find all children called option. Please read [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`options` is a property you will find on HTMLSelectElement objects.

You are looking at a jQuery object.

There is a select element that the jQuery object is wrapped around, you can find it in the property named `0`. (All the elements which match the selector are presented as if the jQuery object were array-like.)

[image: DOM view from question with 0 circled]

```
$("#send_hour")[0].options.length
```

… but if you aren't going to make use of any jQuery features, you might as well use native methods instead:

```
document.querySelector("#send_hour").options.length
```